# Config spark_master_url for multiple spark url in bitnami helm values yaml

Tags: apache-spark

I can't seem to find an option to config spark_master_url on helm values yaml as I setup Spark master ha on zookeeper. What I need is something like this on the spark-worker sts on yaml

- name: SPARK_MASTER_URL
  value: spark://spark-master-svc:7077,**spark-master-svc.standby:7077**

However config above is for the yaml values for spark-worker sts. As I use bitnami helm values, so how to config to add 2nd spark master url on the helm value.

Need some tips here. Thank you

I did not try as it seems not to find an option on helm value.

Expected result : can config 2nd spark master url on helm values

Comment: Can you put in your message more detailed configurations? You might have more than one config file to prepare. Where are they? What are their content? What are exactly the error you're facing? I recommend you to copy also a bit of your console log to show us what is happening to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I managed to add the configuration on bitnami spark helm values.yaml in worker section by adding it below:

  extraEnvVars:
    - name: SPARK_MASTER_URL
      value: spark://spark-master-svc:7077,spark-master-svc.sparkstandby:7077

Thank you